# why do I got the warning "redirect to the same route" even there's no redirection circle

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/student" />
                        <Sw>
                            <Route path="/login" component={login} />
                            <Route path="/404" component={no} />
                            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                        </Sw>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I always got a warning whether I use "/" or "/student" to access the app.

```
index.js:2178 Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/student"
```

I am wondering why did I get this warning, it looks there is no redirect circle.